# "Learning always" vs "always learning"

Tags: word-order

What is the difference between *learning always* and *always learning* in terms of grammar and connotation? If the connotation is the same then which is preferred?

Comment: Context? I don't think "learning always" is grammatical on its own. Only when followed by an infinitive, in which case the *always* does not belong to the *learning* at all, but rather to that infinitive.

Comment: I was in fact thinking of the **always not belonging to learning** - but what about these two statements: "He is learning always" and "He is always learning"?

Comment: The first one places the adverb _always_ at the end of the clause, which is usually possible -- though many would prefer to put a comma or some other punctuation in the written version, and a [comma intonation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/commas.html) in the spoken version. Normally, however, _always_ would go **before** the verb.

Comment: @Thale: I think you need to edit your question text to clarify exactly what you're asking. I suspect it just boils down to whether there's any difference in meaning between placing an adverb before or after the verb it modifies (or possibly, the specific adverb *"always"*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Always* usually goes before the verb. Its placement after the verb may be an instance of anastrophe, a change in word order used to emphasise *always*.

Comment: Nicely put, as always.  I'd only add that putting _always_ at the end of such a two-word phrase seems to add a nostalgic or romantic tone to the expression.  Nothing definitive, but that's simply how it strikes me: "_Learning Always_" sounds warmer and more poetic; "_Always Learning_" sounds more formal and businesslike.  I add this only because the O.P. asked about connotations.  Prattling always, J.R.

Answer (score 0):

To me, *learning always* bring the sense of an incomplete phrase. when using that one has to add another word after the always to make more grammatically correct so to say. *Always learning*, on the other hand, one notices that that's a complete phrase that shows a process that is continuous; it's complete.