# "It doesn't always X" vs "It always doesn't X"

Tags: word-order

When I read these two sentences out loud, I feel that they express very different things.

```
 1. Job interviews don't always go well.
 2. Job interviews always don't go well.
```

At least to me, 1) implies that job interviews often don't go well, but there may be some that go well, and 2) is literally what it says, i.e. job interviews never go well. I believe I am correct as the "[I don't always](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/the-most-interesting-man-in-the-world)" meme also seems to imply the same concept.

Am I correct?

Comment: related, possible duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60173/learning-always-vs-always-learning

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I wonder who or what gives you the idea that the two sentences _would_ mean the same? You only give arguments for them _not_ being the same.

Comment: Because many sentences that vary in the same way **do** mean the same thing.

Comment: "Always don't" seems rather an ugly and needless periphrasis for "never."

Comment: Agreed. But it's grammatical and synonymous.

Comment: I hope whoever downvoted me can give me a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuitions are correct. They **do** mean different things.

The particular difference is predictable from the relative positions
of the negative ***don't*** and the universal temporal quantifier ***always*** in the propositions.
There are two possible positions.

1. The negative can include the quantifier in its scope
   *Job interviews **don't always** go well*, in logical terms
   `NOT` (`ALWAYS` (`Go-Well` (`Job-Interviews`)))
2. The quantifier can include the negative in its scope
   *Job interviews **always don't** go well*, in logical terms
   `ALWAYS` (`NOT` (`Go-Well` (`Job-Interviews`)))

Quantifiers, Negatives, and Modals are all logical operators and have **very** complex interactions.
In particular, any clause with two of them is potentially ambiguous, unless it's compositional,
like your examples. See [The Logic Guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) for further information.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. The *I don't always* meme, which has many fine examples, does indeed affirm this.

The technical reason, if you want one, comes intuitively if we consider the order of operations, given by the positioning of the words within the clause they form.

Taking your sentences as you gave them, then:

> Job interviews **don't always** go well.

In this sentence, *always* is applied to the act of 'going well', and *don't* is subsequently applied to *always*, with the effect of negating it. In set theory terms, in the complete set of all job interviews ever conducted (or to be conducted), it is **not** true that they all will go well. In other words, at least one of them won't.

This phrasing is very common, although depending on the ratio of job interviews going well versus not going well, one might substitute 'don't always' for something that indicates the broad probability of the success of job interviews - such as *rarely*, *sometimes*, or *often*.

> Job interviews **always don't** go well.

In this sentence however, the inversion of *don't* and *always* radically changes the logical proposition indicated by the phrase. Here, *don't* is applied to negate the act of 'going well', and *always* is applied to to *don't*, making this negation universal. In set theory terms, in the complete set of all job interviews ever conducted (or to be conducted), it **is** true that they will all **not** go well.

This phrasing, however, is less common - *always don't* would much more naturally be substituted for *never*, a perfect word for assigning the condition of always being false.

Comment: Right, using "never" makes more sense in the second case.