# Using "may not" when something is not sometimes true

Tags: modal-verbs

When we want to say something is **sometimes** true or happens **sometimes**, we use "can":

1. *A vegetarian diet **can** provide enough calories for a child's normal growth.*

What modal would you use if you wanted to say something is **not sometimes** true or **doesn't** happen **sometimes**? Would you use "may not"?

2. *A vegetarian diet **may not** provide enough calories for a child's normal growth.*

I think we wouldn't use "can't" there. Am I right?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "not sometimes true". "Not sometimes" is not the idiomatic English for anything.

Comment: ***Sometimes** a vegetarian diet doesn't provide enough calories for a child's normal growth.*

Comment: Yes; 'can' is used sometimes to mean 'may', but 'can't' means 'can't possibly'. Modals are finicky beasts.

Comment: Instead of _not sometimes true_ we say _sometimes not true_ or, better still, _not always true_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that

- **`Modals`**, like *may,* and
- **`Negatives`**, like *not,*

are both *Operators* (along with **`Quantifiers`**, like *every*).

All operators have *Scope*; that is, they are meaningful only within some part of the sentence, and not outside it. And when there are two operators in a sentence -- a negative with a modal, as here, or [a negative with a quantifier](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/183118/15299), or a quantifier with a modal, or two modals, etc. -- there are two scopes covering parts of the same sentence, and one is usually inside another. This makes for differences and confusions.

In the case of `Modal + Negative`, consider

1. *"Cinderella may not attend the ball", said her stepmother.*
2. *"This may not be the right place", said the driver.*

First, note that *may not* refers to permission and prohibition in (1), but only to possibility or probability in (2). This is the distinction between [Deontic Modals and Epistemic Modals](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/275686/15299); (1) is deontic and (2) is epistemic.

> In what follows, `Possible` stands for both epistemic and deontic modality -- *may* is a `Possible` modal, not a `Necessary` modal like *must*.

Second, note that the scope of the negative in (1) includes the scope of deontic *may*. That is, (1) means that permission (*may*) is negated (*not*); logically,

- *It is not true that "Cinderella may attend the ball".*
  symbolically, `Not` (`Possible` (*Attend* (*Cinderella, ball*)))

Third, note that the scope of the epistemic *may* in (2) includes the scope of the negative *not*. That is, (2) means that negation ("this is not correct) is possible; logically,

- *It may be that "this is not the correct place".*
  symbolically, `Possible` (`Not` (*Correct* (`This place`)))

So that's the way it is with *may not* -- it has two meanings, and they're **different** in how they work.

Getting back to the original question, let me note that *sometimes* is a quantifier, and has its own scope, which helps complicate matters. And the phrase *not sometimes true* is, as noted in the comments, already unclear, so let's just say that [modals and negatives and quantifiers](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20modal%20negative%20quantifier) are very complex and not given to easy explanations.

Comment: Thank you....a) Is the modality expressed by "may" in sentence 2) in the OP, an **epistemic** modality? b) Can I paraphrase sentences 1) and 2) in the OP like this: 1) *It is **possible** for a vegetarian diet to provide enough calories...* 2) *It is **possible** for a vegetarian diet to **not** provide enough calories...*?

Comment: (a) Yes, it's epistemic. (b) Yes, though the second one has a split infinitive, it has the right  scope relation. Note that we use the word _possible_ in both epistemic ways and deontic ways (deontic _possible_ as in _That will not be possible for you as a first-year student_).

Comment: One more question: Do you distinguish between the following: 1) *It **is possible that** a vegetarian diet **doesn't** provide enough calories for a child's normal growth*. and 2) *It **is possible for** a vegetarian diet to **not** provide enough calories for a child's normal growth*?

Comment: There's no meaning difference, but obviously one must distinguish an infinitive complement from a tensed _that_ complement syntactically. _Possible_ takes both of those types of complement, but not embedded questions or gerund clauses, the other two complement types in English. That's about par for the course with a modal predicate adjective.